# $Pr(X+Y \geq \frac{\pi}{2})$

Tags: calculus, probability, algebra-precalculus, statistics

I want to find $Pr(X+Y \geq \frac{\pi}{2})$ for joint pdf $f_{X,Y}(x,y) = x \cos y, 0 \lt x \lt \frac{\pi}{2}, 0 \lt y \lt x, 0$ otherwise.

I believe I have found conditional pdf of $Y$ given $X=x$ to be $\frac{\cos y}{\sin x}$, but I am unsure where to go from here. Please help!${}{}$

Comment: Is there something wrong with the range of x?  Should it be $0\leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: @satishramanathan yes sorry

Comment: Draw the domain of $(X,Y)$ (it's a triangle), add the constraint $Y\leq \pi/2-X$ (you get a smaller triangle). Then integrate $f(x,y)$ on it. It's a double integral with bounds $x \in [\pi/4,  \pi/2]$, $y\in [\pi/2-x, x]$.

Comment: (sorry, the constraint is $Y\geq \pi/2-X$, it was a latex typo, the integral bounds are right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The plot of the joint pdf is quite fun:

[image]

OP wrote: "I want to find $Pr(X+Y \geq \frac{\pi}{2})$"

If you have access to a computer algebra system, it is quite easy to automatically solve such problems. For your problem, random variables $(X,Y)$ have joint pdf $f(x,y)$:

```
        f  = x Cos[y] Boole[0 < y < x];       
 domain[f] = {{x, 0, Pi/2}, {y, 0, Pi/2}};
```

You seek:

```
Prob[x + y > Pi/2, f]
```

which returns:

> $\frac{1}{4} \pi  \left(\sqrt{2}-2\right)+1$

All done.

**Notes**

1. I am using here the `Prob` function from the *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* to do the nitty gritties. As disclosure, I should add that I am one of the authors.